# FreeBSD Jails in Mac OS X

Tags: security, osx-snow-leopard, virtualization, freebsd, chroot-jail

I was wondering if FreeBSD Jails are available on Mac OS X or perhaps an equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

Jails are not available on OSX.

The closest alternative with a similar application for security available would be **chroot**.

The differences, benefits and drawbacks of chroot vs. jail can fill days worth of discussion / flamewars. Depending on what you try to accomplish, chroots may however be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. For info, the question was once asked on the FreeBSD [forum](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=6350)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run jails with xhyve on macos.

Comment: How? I guess running jails _inside_ any virtualization on Mac OS is not what OP asked for; but rather for a _native_ process isolation solution _without_ running an OS kernel supporting it.